# How to count the number of common occurrences between two cells with CSV in Google Sheets

Tags: csv, google-sheets

**Motive:** I am trying to compare 2 cells with comma separated values within each and find out the number of common occurrences. Also based on the number of common occurrences and Experience Input Values, i want to print a certain keyword.

**Attaching The Screenshot:**[image: search between 2 cells with csv]

**GOAL:** The mentioned text in Deep Red are my goals:
1. Count the number of common words between B2 & B6
2. Print B1 IF certain conditions are true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B11:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(TRIM(SPLIT(B2,","))=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(B6,",")))))
```

B12:

```
=IF(AND(B11>50,B7>=B3,B7<=B4),B1,"")
```